# Ocultar rows de uma pickerview quando selecionado um item de outra pickerview - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Criei um pickerview utilizando um array multidimensional, precisaria ocultar alguns itens do `picker4` depois que eu selecionasse o primeiro item do `picker3`.

```
class ViewControllerEspessuras: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    var data = [["1.50","1.60","1.67","1.74"],
                ["-10.00 Esf.","-9.00 Esf.","-8.00 Esf.","-7.00 Esf.","-6.00 Esf.","-5.00 Esf.","-4.00 Esf.","-3.00 Esf.","-2.00 Esf.","-1.00 Esf.","Plano","+1.00 Esf.","+2.00 Esf.","+3.00 Esf.","+4.00 Esf.","+5.00 Esf.","+6.00 Esf.","+7.00 Esf.","+8.00 Esf.","+9.00 Esf.","+10.00 Esf."],
                ["1.50","1.60","1.67","1.74"],
                ["-10.00 Esf.","-9.00 Esf.","-8.00 Esf.","-7.00 Esf.","-6.00 Esf.","-5.00 Esf.","-4.00 Esf.","-3.00 Esf.","-2.00 Esf.","-1.00 Esf.","Plano","+1.00 Esf.","+2.00 Esf.","+3.00 Esf.","+4.00 Esf.","+5.00 Esf.","+6.00 Esf.","+7.00 Esf.","+8.00 Esf.","+9.00 Esf.","+10.00 Esf."]]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return data[component].count
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return data[component][row]
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let picker1 = data[0][pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
        let picker2 = data[1][pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(1)]
        let picker3 = data[2][pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(2)]
        let picker4 = data[3][pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(3)]
    }       
}
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Você deve alterar seu `numberOfRowsInComponent` e `titleForRow forComponent` para que eles levem em consideração a seleção do terceiro.

Feito isso é só chamar `reloadComponent` do último quando o terceiro muda.

Referências podem ser encontradas [nessa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34700310/2305521) resposta do SO (em inglês)